# How to get total sales for each product in Order Details table in Northwind database in a single statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

How to get total sales for each product in Order Details table in Northwind database in a single statement?

I know how to do this:

```
select productid,  UnitPrice * (1 - Discount) * sum(Quantity) 
  from [Order Details]
    group by ProductID,UnitPrice, Discount
```

I get multiple rows for each productid and then I can run another query to get one sum for each productid. **Note that the discount can be different for the same productid**.

I would like to do it all in a single SQL statement. How?

Comment: Only use `group by ProductID`

Comment: Doesn't work. UnitPrice and Discount have to be an aggregate function or be in a group by

Comment: You probably want: `sum(UnitPrice * (1 - Discount) * Quantity)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just extract your `sum` function to sum the price for each row individually, instead of just summing the quantity (this should be OK mathematically due to the [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of multiplication over addition):

```
SELECT   productid,  SUM(UnitPrice * (1 - Discount) * Quantity)
FROM     [Order Details]
GROUP BY ProductID
```